# How To Modify Each Line Of SQL File

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, mysqli

I need to modify many SQL statements to include an incremented number to keep track of each word in the 'paragraph' column. Sorry, but my PHP skills are limited. I am thinking a foreach loop after reading the file, but can't come up with anything to actually modify the lines to include each a value for each word.

Current SQL:

```
INSERT INTO `book` VALUES(1, 1, 1, 'These are the words in a sentence in a chapter in a book.');
INSERT INTO `book` VALUES(1, 1, 2, 'These are the words in the second sentence in a chapter in a book.');
INSERT INTO `book` VALUES(1, 1, 3, 'These are the words in the third sentence in a chapter in a book.');
...and so on.
```

The current VALUES are 'book', 'chapter, 'paragraph_number', 'paragraph'.

Goal:

```
INSERT INTO `book` VALUES(1, 1, 1, 1,'These');
INSERT INTO `book` VALUES(1, 1, 1, 2,'are');
INSERT INTO `book` VALUES(1, 1, 1, 3,'the');
INSERT INTO `book` VALUES(1, 1, 1, 4,'words');
```

The -new- VALUES are 'book', 'chapter, 'paragraph_number', 'paragraph', 'word_number'.

I already have the book, chapter, and paragraph number.

For example:

```
INSERT INTO `book` VALUES(1, 5, 16, 'This is a sentence from book 1, chapter 5, paragraph 16.');
```

would convert to:

```
INSERT INTO `book` VALUES(1, 5, 16, 1,'This');
INSERT INTO `book` VALUES(1, 5, 16, 2,'is');
INSERT INTO `book` VALUES(1, 5, 16, 3,'a');
INSERT INTO `book` VALUES(1, 5, 16, 4,'sentence');
INSERT INTO `book` VALUES(1, 5, 16, 5,'from');
INSERT INTO `book` VALUES(1, 5, 16, 6,'book');
INSERT INTO `book` VALUES(1, 5, 16, 7,'1,');
INSERT INTO `book` VALUES(1, 5, 16, 8,'chapter');
INSERT INTO `book` VALUES(1, 5, 16, 9,'5,');
INSERT INTO `book` VALUES(1, 5, 16, 10,'paragraph');
INSERT INTO `book` VALUES(1, 5, 16, 11,'16.');
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated ...Thanks!

EDIT: Below is the code that worked ....based off of Akam's answer ...I changed the SQL statement. Added the [SEP] to separate the text from the other data which allowed me to work with the text. Also, added the $x to increment the word count.

SQL:

```
1, 1, 1,[SEP]These are the words in sentence 1 in chapter 1 in a book.
1, 1, 2,[SEP]These are the words in sentence 2 in chapter 1 in a book.
```

PHP:

```
$lines = file('my-book.sql');
$query = "INSERT INTO `book` VALUES \n";

foreach ($lines as $line)
{
    $part = preg_split("/\[SEP\]/", $line);
    $part[1] = preg_replace('~[\r\n]+~', '', $part[1]);
    $words = preg_split("/\s+/", $part[1]);

    $x = 1;
    foreach($words as $word)
    {
        $values[] = "(".$part[0]." ".$x.", '".$word."')";
        $x++;
    }

}

$new_lines = implode(",\n", $values);
$new_lines = $query.$new_lines.";";
echo $new_lines;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$text = 'This is a sentence from book 1, chapter 5, paragraph 16.';
$words = preg_split("/\s+/", $text);
$query = "INSERT INTO `book` VALUES \n";
foreach($words as $word){
 $values[] = "(1, 5, 16, 1,'$word')";
}
$finalquery = $query.implode(",\n", $values);
echo $finalquery.";";
?>
```

Output:

```
INSERT INTO `book` VALUES 
(1, 5, 16, 1,'This'),
(1, 5, 16, 1,'is'),
(1, 5, 16, 1,'a'),
(1, 5, 16, 1,'sentence'),
(1, 5, 16, 1,'from'),
(1, 5, 16, 1,'book'),
(1, 5, 16, 1,'1,'),
(1, 5, 16, 1,'chapter'),
(1, 5, 16, 1,'5,'),
(1, 5, 16, 1,'paragraph'),
(1, 5, 16, 1,'16.');
```

Comment: Thanks Akam! I managed to use your code as the base to do what I needed it to do. See edits in the OP.